# How to combine the Kruskal's algorithm and the adjacency matrix from a file?

Tags: python, algorithm, graph

```
N, M = map(int, input().split())
Edges = []
for i in range(M):
    start, end, weight = map(int, input().split())
    Edges.append([weight, start, end])
Edges.sort()
Comp = [i for i in range(N)]
Ans = 0
for weight, start, end in Edges:
    if Comp[start] != Comp[end]:
        Ans += weight
        a = Comp[start]
        b = Comp[end]
        for i in range(N):
            if Comp[i] == b:
                Comp[i] = a
```

**How can this algorithm (above) be combined with the file containing the adjacency matrix?**

Code that reads a matrix from a file:

```
with open('in.txt') as f:
    matrix = [list(map(int, row.split())) for row in f.readlines()]
```

Comment: combined for what?

Comment: This matrix is in the file. I need to use the data from the file for the algorithm.

Comment: would it be possible for you to upload the file to google drive and send me a shareable link so I can view the format of the data in the file

Comment: https://cloud.mail.ru/public/3Ugv/47CDMbGrZ

Comment: press the button Скачать

Comment: I'm sorry but what is your desired output. The "Code that reads a matrix from a file:" produces a list of lists with each number on each line like so

[[0, 22, 25, 0, 24, 0, 14, 15, 15, 0], [22, 0, 29, 29, 9, 6, 0, 25, 14, 28], [25, 29, 0, 5, 0, 15, 19, 6, 24, 11], [0, 29, 5, 0, 21, 11, 12, 22, 7, 22], [24, 9, 0, 21, 0, 8, 13, 12, 9, 18], [0, 6, 15, 11, 8, 0, 11, 13, 0, 11], [14, 0, 19, 12, 13, 11, 0, 9, 19, 26], [15, 25, 6, 22, 12, 13, 9, 0, 20, 17], [15, 14, 24, 7, 9, 0, 19, 20, 0, 24], [0, 28, 11, 22, 18, 11, 26, 17, 24, 0]]

what do you expect "Kruskal's algorithm" supposed to produce?

Comment: how much prior programming knowledge do you have?

Comment: Task: to Write a program that, according to the Kraskala algorithm, finds the skeleton of the minimum weight for a connected weighted undirected graph having 10 vertices. The graph is given by the adjacency matrix(0 means that there is no corresponding arc). Read data from file. Print the edges of the skeleton of the minimum weight in the order of their attachment and the weight of the skeleton.

Comment: https://cloud.mail.ru/public/4Lfq/2dwdn9oPK

Comment: What problem are you having? Put the edges from the adjacency matrix into the edge list.